# Create a computed column on a datetime

Tags: sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

I have a nullable DateTime column in my SQL Server 2005 table called DateTimeDeleted.

I'd like to have a BIT type computed column that is 1 if DateTimeDeleted is not null, otherwise 0. However, I can't seem to get the syntax for the formula correct.

I've tried:

```
(TsDeleted IS NULL) = 0
```

but it gives me a syntax error.

Help! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Alter Table MyTableName 
  Add IsDeleted As 
     (Case When [DateTimeDeleted] Is Null 
       Then (0) Else (1) End)
```

This will output as an integer... If you really want it to be a bit, then:

```
Alter Table MyTableName 
  Add IsDeleted As 
     cast( (Case When [DateTimeDeleted] Is Null 
       Then (0) Else (1) End) as Bit)
```

Comment: THanks Charles - that worked fine. Actually I have used that before, but I must have forgotten about it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
update table
set IsDeleted = case when DateTimeDeleted is null then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: This will set a bit column, but I think he's looking for a way to construct a computed column.  A computed column must be an expression but can't be a subquery.

Answer (score -1):

This will work, basically it does a divide by itself if it's not null and then divide 0 by 1 if it's NULL

```
CONVERT(INT,IsNULL(DateTimeDeleted,0))/CONVERT(INT,IsNULL(DateTimeDeleted,1))
```

Comment: Isn't this a bit convoluted?  I mean it's clever, but it's hard to read, the intention isn't clear, and it's performing unnecessary maths.