# Compute Column on MySQL Create Table query String

Tags: mysql, calculated-columns

I'm bit new to mysql. I tried to compute column with help of set command to compute new column but it isn't execute (1064 error).

So my question is:-

> Is it possible to add query for creating compute column with *create table* query string? If yes then how? and If no then why. What should be best alternative for this.

I think, I can also achieve this using `TRIGGER` but I tried to avoid this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441869/create-a-computed-column-on-a-datetime) is a nice example for this but this can't be applicable for data that will be inserted.

I had tried this as follow

```
create table `call_detail` (`service_key` integer not null,
`called` datetime not null,
`called_stamp` integer not null 
        SET  (1 if HOUR(`called`)<10 else 2 if HOUR(`called`)<16 else 3 if HOUR(`called`)<24
            else -1),
PRIMARY KEY (`service_key`) 
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is

1. not possible
2. and your syntax is totally wrong
3. and where does `_date` come from?

I'd suggest you use VIEWs for this. This way you don't loose information you might need later and still get what you want.

```
CREATE VIEW v_call_detail AS
SELECT 
c.*,
CASE WHEN HOUR(created_modified) < 10 THEN 1
     WHEN HOUR(created_modified) BETWEEN 10 AND 15 THEN 2 
     WHEN HOUR(created_modified) BETWEEN 16 AND 23 THEN 3
     ELSE -1
END AS called_stamp
FROM
call_detail c
```

This assumes you have a column created_modified in your table which indicates when a row was inserted or modified. Create the table like this:

```
create table `call_detail` (`service_key` integer not null,
`called` datetime not null,
created_modified timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`service_key`) /*changed primary key, since you don't have a column `_ID`*/
);
```

Comment: but from this I have to perform view maintenance frequently after adding data to parent table, which is best if possible to avoid...

Comment: View maintenance? Not when you're adding rows. When you are frequently adding columns you surely should rethink your database design.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have computed columns like that, the thread you are linking to are for MSSQL.

You have a few options here as I see it

- Use a trigger to update the column
- Create a view
- Set up a cron job to periodically update the table

Comment: yep I know... Actually the link I provide don't compute column, it alter table and add column... Anyway thanks for answer though I would't expect this as answer

Comment: The thread you were linking to alters the table and adds a computed column. Which is not possible in MySQL.